# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

i am getting below error.

Warning: require_once(C:\inetpub\vhosts\ashahealth.com\httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\ashahealth.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\load.php on line 468

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\ashahealth.com\httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php' (include_path='.;.\includes;.\pear') in C:\inetpub\vhosts\ashahealth.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\load.php on line 468
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

For reference please find the below url

http://ashahealth.com

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You are missing the `wp-includes/wp-db.php` file from the WordPress core, isn't this obvious from the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp-db.php file was missing in wp-includes.